# Transaction replication and Primary key Violation

Tags: transactions, replication

SQL Server 2000 SP2 8.00.760

Error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__@snapshot_seqnos__3B9B84A9'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object '#3AA76070'

.

I am getting this error in Dist. agent. I can't drop replication. What is the easiest way to figure out what is causing this and how can I avoid it. I even tried Dist. Agent Profile name "Continue on data consistency errors."